# Typescript factory function signatures

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to indicate that a factory function in Typescript?

```
function getHelp (with) : SomeSignatureHere {      
   return function () {
     return 'Help with '+with;
   }
}
```

Comment: The word [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generator_functions) means something specific in JavaScript (it's a type of iterator).  Looks like you're just talking about a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type).  In this case, `()=>string` should work in place of `SomeSignatureHere`.

Comment: Just to add to what jcalz is saying (and he is 100% right) you could just let the compiler infer the function type. No need for an explicit annotation at least not in the code you posted. Also if you don't specify anything and hover over the `getHelp` signature you will see the inferred types in the signature  (which helps as you can then just type it in explicitly if you want)

Comment: @jcalz that I was a mistake, I mean't factory, I have changed that now.